# Disallowing certain user from dumping database (MySQL)

Tags: backup, mysql

Under the privileges that can be assigned to a user, I can't find whether to allow or disallow a user from being able to dump a database.

I want to disallow a user from taking backup of a database.

Answer (score 4):

If a user has read access to the database he will be able to dump the database one way or the other - if he can read it, he can choose to save it somewhere as well.

Comment: from security view, that is not a very good solution, is it? Isn't there any solution at all?

Comment: @Johan Why would a user be allowed to view every single record but not dump the db? They amount to the same thing, i.e. permission to read the contents of the db.

Comment: I have a very specific situation where I want to make it more difficult for copying data from the database, True, viewing is still a similar risk. It's more time consuming to browse within a 1GB database and view the records one by one than dumping it within seconds.

Comment: Database dump is a whole database in a file. To create such dump you need to 1. read the contents of the database, 2. save it to a file.

If user has access to the database he can read it (step 1, check) and can do whatever he wants with the data he just read, outside MySQL server, like for example save it - even copy&paste into notepad or use one of many db backup tools (step 2, check). 

To sum up: if you have access to database you can't be stopped from saving the data. It's just impossible.

Comment: Ok, Can't we set a limit on the dump file size? My DB is almost 1GB in size, if we limit it to lets say 10mb, than it will be useless to use the dump command.

Comment: You can set maximum number of queries per hour for an user, but `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE TRUE;` will still fetch whole table in 1 query. The only option here is denying direct access to the tables and allow reading data only through provided functions that will limit the amount of data fetched, but that's not always an option and requires a lot extra work.

Comment: mm, seems complicated and not worth it, will look for a solution and update my post when solved it.

Comment: Perhaps limit the user to the `EXECUTE` permission only and then create stored procedures that the user can run to perform their job? I don't know what you'd run into as far as preventing the user from modifying or creating their own procs, but.. just an idea

Answer (score 2):

According the [**MySQL Documentation on mysqldump**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html):

> mysqldump requires at least the SELECT privilege for dumped tables, SHOW VIEW for dumped views, and LOCK TABLES if the --single-transaction option is not used. Certain options might require other privileges as noted in the option descriptions.

You could remove `SELECT`, `LOCK TABLES` and `SHOW VIEW` privileges, but that's about it. Of course, taking away `SELECT` kind of defeats the purpose of wanting to connect to a database.

You may want to consider tweeking the OS privileges of users in terms of where they can/cannot write their data.

Comment: Even if you tweak the users permissions to deny writing the data on the server he can still redirect the output outside of the box, so basically I think if he/she has the SELECT permissions you can't do much :)